# Both HD and SD graphics on retina display

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I am trying to upgrade my game to take advantage of the retina display. Here are the things i got confused about. Please help me out.

First, please correct me if i'm wrong on this.
With the retina display enabled, Cocos2d will try to look for -hd files (for example Dog-hd.png) and use them.
If it can't find any, then it's going to load the original Dog.png WITHOUT scaling it up by 2.
My problem is that I don't have (or don't want) all the graphics to be in high resolution but I still want everything to be the same size as before, with a few objects in HD.
If I just leave the SD graphics as they are, they will look 1/2 as large as before on a retina display.

What are the things I can do to make it recognize SD graphics and scale them up by 2 automatically in the code? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about Cocos2d, but the standard is to use `@2x` postfix. So `imagename.png` and `imagename@2x.png` would be the file names to automatically get used with `UIImage`'s `imageWithName`

Comment: Cocos2D does not work well with the @2x format, there are compatibility issues (but it's not mentioned what they are): http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Answer (score 2):

Cocoa handles this for you quite seamlessly.  Use `myImage.png` for standard and `myImage@2x.png` for retina images.  When loading an image from a xib, storyboard, or `UIImage imageNamed:`, it will automatically select the correct image.  In addition, images displayed as a size different than the source will automatically appear higher resolution on retina displays and lower resolution on non-retina displays regardless of the `@2x` suffix.

Comment: Cocos2D does not work well with the @2x format, there are compatibility issues (but it's not mentioned what they are): http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Comment: Does the texture cache handle the file names correctly? One of the issues may be that you'll likely have to remove either image.png or image@2x.png manually from texture cache if you want to remove the texture, whereas with -hd cocos2d handles the conversion to -hd internally, so you just need to remove image.png in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one graphic for both SD and HD, it will ok on non-retina display but look bit blurry on retina... but as per performance there is no problem if you are going with cocos2d.

you have to use ccp for positioning, boundingBox for content size, and avoid static values in your code.. i think everything will be fine . :)

if you have any more problem regarding this you can post a new comment or question here.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I'm still confused about how only one graphic would work. Say I have an SD png that takes the whole non-retina display. On a retina display the same SD png will shrink to half the size instead of taking the whole screen and looking blurry. I tried this and cocos2d did not automatically scale up the SD graphics. Can you explain in a bit detail how it would work with only one SD graphic as you said? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use upscaled SD graphics in a Retina enabled cocos2d app, you must change the scale property of the node:

```
// upscaling a sprite that uses SD image
sprite.scale *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
```

You have two ways of finding out if the sprite uses only an HD texture. One, you just know it and apply the above code to all sprites that don't use HD images. Second, you can check for the existence of the -hd version of the image.

```
NSString* imageFile = @"someimage.png"
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:imageFile];
NSString* fullFile = [CCFileUtils fullPathFromRelativePath:imageFile];
if ([fullFile hasSuffix:@"-hd.png"])
{
    // upscaling sprite because it uses an SD image
    sprite.scale *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
}
```

Untested but should work.